# How do I write this code to not show default on label_submit?

Tags: comment-form

I am programming a comments section on a WordPress theme I am developing, here is the code in comments.php:

```
 <div class="comments">
  <h2>Comments</h2>
   <?php $args = array(
        'walker'                => null,
        'max_depth'             => '',
        'style'                 => 'ul',
        'callback'              => null,
        'end-callback'          => null,
        'type'                  => 'all',
        'reply_text'            => 'Reply',
        'page'                  => '',
        'per_page'              => '',
        'avatar_size'           => 80,
        'reverse_top_level'     => null,
        'reverse_children'      => '',
        'format'                => 'html5', // or 'xhtml' if no 'HTML5' theme support
        'short_ping'            => false, // @since 3.6
        'echo'                  => true // boolean, default is true
     );
   ?>

   <?php wp_list_comments($args, $comments); ?>

   <?php
        $form_args = array(
                'label_submit'          => 'Send',
                'title_reply'           => 'Write a Reply or Comment',
                'comment_notes_after'   => '',
                'comment_field'         => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">'._x('Comment','noun').'</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
        );

        comment_form($forms_args);
   ?>
</div>
```

Do you see how under the $form_args array 'label_submit' => 'Send'. However, it is still rendering the default which is 'Post Comment' on the browser. I have tried different ways, but I cannot seem to get my 'Send' to override the 'Post Comment'.

Answer (score 0):

I researched the WordPress Codex some more and analyzed the code I posted here and if you look at the top where it says $form_args, but then in comment_form($forms_args):

```
<?php
        $form_args = array(
                'label_submit'          => 'Send',
                'title_reply'           => 'Write a Reply or Comment',
                'comment_notes_after'   => '',
                'comment_field'         => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">'._x('Comment','noun').'</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
        );

        comment_form($forms_args);
   ?>
```

So I just needed to remove the s from what I passed into comment_form:

```
<?php
        $form_args = array(
                'label_submit'          => 'Send',
                'title_reply'           => 'Write a Reply or Comment',
                'comment_notes_after'   => '',
                'comment_field'         => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">'._x('Comment','noun').'</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
        );

        comment_form($form_args);
```